# C++ interfaces - what are my options?

Tags: c++, interface

Diving back into the world of C++, and experimenting with interfaces. I can find plenty of online examples, but 99% of them are trivial 'all-in-one-file'.

Interfaces can be classified into 3 basic types- interfaces where (all|some|zero) functions must be overridden in a concrete subclass (all|some|zero pure virtual functions in c++ parlance).

Is it possible to implement any of the 3 in a single header file? (no .cpp twin) Why/why not? How? If not, what are my options for the .h/.cpp pair?

Some of the options I have seen are: virtual destructor, protected destructor, inline destructor, pure virtual destructor with an implementation,... my head is spinning!

EDIT: meant pure virtual, not virtual void

Comment: My current toy setup is: an IList interface, two implementation classes (Vector and LinkedLink) and a tester class.

Comment: You don't need a CPP file ... you could define it all inline ...

Comment: what do you mean with "implement in a single header file"? Pure virtual classes (classes with only virtual member functions without an implementation) never have a .cpp...

Comment: @MFH Thats not true. In the world of C++ you can still have those pure virtual member functions implemented by pure virtual classes, i.e you can place implementation into .cpp

Comment: @RomanSaveljev I was talking about meaningful usage, having a pure virtual class in a .cpp is seldomly useful. Obviously the standard doesn't have any restrictions of that kind...

Comment: @MFH I will post meaningful usage, hang on :)

Answer (score 1):

- If you make your interface pure virtual, the compiler will give an error if you forget to implement a method in your concrete class.
- If there are methods that have some sane default implementation you can provide it, but this is just a convenience.
- If you make the destructor virtual, you can `delete` the object via its interface pointer rather than requiring the concrete object pointer.

Herb Sutter has some interesting thoughts on interfaces which are at direct odds with the way most of us implement an interface: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm

Comment: So, if I make an default implementation for even one function, best practice would be to split it into a .cpp file, otherwise the concrete classes would each include said implementation (and fail to compile) correct?

Comment: The function can stay in the header, if you make it inline. Otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

**Read this awesome piece of internet wisdom**: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html

1) You never need a .cpp file, you can code all your programs in .h, but doing this is terrible style and will inevitabely slow your compilation.

```
MyClass : public MyInterface {
    public:
    virtual void myFunction() {
        // override and implemenht
    }
};
```

2) When inheriting classes you don't need to worry about declaring your destructor to be virtual, but you need to make sure that classes you are inheriting from have virtual destructors. Otherwise you might be faced with memory leaks. In so far as I know this is not necessary for interface classes with only pure virtual functions.

Destructor being inline makes no difference to you.

Destructor being declared as void is something that should give you a compiler error :).

*Edit:*
About the 3 types of interfaces, I am getting the sense that you are a little bit confused and this is hampering your googling.

An interface is usually a class that has no functions defined and you must inherit and implement all of them.

A class that has some functionality but still has some pure virtuals is usually called abstract.

When 'zero' functions must be overridden this is neither an interface nor an abstract class, it is just a plain old class that you can inherit and do whatever.

Check out the C++ faq.

Comment: As far as the 3 types, I think I was trying to transfer the objective-c concept of @ optional within a @ protocol, it looks like there isn't an equivalent.

Comment: @zjaquish No, and I suspect the reason why Objective-C needs these concepts is dynamic binding. Since C++ uses compile-time binding it will force you to implement all methods that aren't implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Interface where all functions must be overridden by a concrete subclass is called `interface`

Interface where some functions must be overridden by a concrete subclass is called `abstract class`

Interface where zero functions must be overridden by a concrete subclass is called `class`.

You can implement virtual member functions inside header file. They will not inline though, because they have to have address to be placed into virtual table.

> ... my head is spinning!

To get it spinning more you can also have `pure virtual destructor`. This is useful trick when you want to have abstract class, but no real useful method to put pure virtual:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A() = 0;
};

A::~A() {}

class B : public A
{
public:
    ~B() {}
};
```

Class A has destructor implemented, but it still can not be instantiated directly, because it is interface. Yet, when it comes to destroying `B` compiler has to obey to protocol and call ~A(). That is why you have to implement it